# JUnit: Setting Transaction boundry for Test Class

Tags: java, spring, junit, junit4, spring-test

I want to start the database transactions before start of any test method and rollback all transactions at the end of running all tests.

How to do thing?What annotations should I use ?

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"/testApplicationContext.xml"})
public class MyTests{

   public void setUp(){
    //Insert temporary data to Database
   }

   @Test
   public void testOne(){
     //Do some DB transactions
   }

   @Test void testTwo(){
     //Do some more DB transactions
   }

   public void tearDown(){
   //Need to rollback all transactions
   }


}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use @Before to launch method before any test and @After to launch method after every test. Use @Transactional spring's annotation over a method or over a class to start transaction and @Rollback to rollback everything done in transaction.

```
@Before   
public void setUp(){
    //set up, before every test method
}

@Transactional
@Test
public void test(){
}

@Rollback
@After
public void tearDown(){
   //tear down after every test method
}
```

Also there is [same issue solved in another way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4098541/685962).

Answer (score 6):

In Spring just add `@Transactional` annotation over your test case class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"/testApplicationContext.xml"})
@Transactional   //CRUCIAL!
public class MyTests{
```

Check out [official documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html) for very in-depth details, including `@TransactionConfiguration`, `@BeforeTransaction`, `@AfterTransaction` and other features.

Comment: Yes, it is the simplest approach, but generally managing transactions in tests using `@Transactional` is strongly discouraged. You even wrote article on that topic: [Spring Pitfalls: Transactional tests considered harmful](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/12/spring-pitfalls-transactional-tests.html)  :)

Comment: I normally use the method given above but @G.Demecki is correct, I've been bitten a few times that way.

Answer (score 1):

Use the annotation `@Before` for methods that have to run before every testmethod and `@After` to run after every testmethod.

You can take [this article](http://selftechy.com/2011/05/17/junit4-before-vs-beforeclass-after-vs-afterclass) as a reference.