# Run JUnit @Before and @After in their own transaction

Tags: java, spring, junit, transactions

Closest question I've found is here:

[JUnit: Setting Transaction boundry for Test Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11948147/junit-setting-transaction-boundry-for-test-class)

The accepted answer gives a way for the whole test to run in a transaction, but what I'm trying to do is *avoid* wrapping the test case in a transaction. Is there any way of doing this?

Annotating the methods with @Transactional:

```
@Transactional
@Before
public void setUp(){
    //set up, before every test method
}

@Test
public void test(){
}

@Transactional
@After
public void tearDown(){
   //tear down after every test method
}
```

Does not work (I think it's to do with Spring proxies from what I've read).

This is to do with a refactoring task where we currently have our abstract integration test base class wrapping every test in a transaction. I'm trying to undo that, but all our integration tests uses DAO's (non-transactional) to set up and tear down the database. I'd like to be able to rewrap the DAO's in transactional methods in just the setUp and tearDown methods (so I don't have to spend days refactoring the many test classes).

Unless there are better solutions?

Thanks